# Creating a power-point file reader ( pptx )

Tags: powerpoint

I'm looking for an open-source pptx reader (preferred in C# ) to modify it and put it into a 3D engine ( customer request ), or at least a tutorial on the basics. I already searched on google but can't find any useful resources.

I know it's possible to create a new reader by reading the pptx files documentation ( ECMA ), but this seems to be a huge project anyway and I would prefer if I'm able to build this component on some existing code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Your options

The best option to use really depends on the modifications you need to do. If you want to be able to heavily manipulate the PowerPoint presentation, draw new shapes, rotate shapes, add charts, add slides or master slides etc. you may find an abstraction layer like the Aspose.Slides library (proprietary) very useful.

If you do not want to pay for the library, the `OpenXML` formats are available to you in .NET. They allow you to manipulate every aspect of the PPTX document without the need for Interop/COM as they parse the XML inside the PPTX.

From personal experience, having used both, Aspose is a far easier solution but one that provides some overhead and of course has a cost. The OpenXML route is light to use, but requires some learning curve.

Last but not least, you can take a look at [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) which achieves something similar to Aspose, it is a little lighter and has reduced functionality. It also covers other formats and does not require Office installs on the machine.

To sum your options:

- [Aspose.Slides](http://aspose.com) ($$)
- [OpenXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee358825.aspx) (curve, but flexibility)
- [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) (limited functionality)

### My advice

If you need to do some simple modifications (e.g. extract a slide, change a bit of text somewhere, replace an image) I would go with OpenXML.

If you want to draw slides in a bespoke manner, I would go with Aspose. I have used Aspose in a 50.000 LoC application to build hundreds of thousands of PowerPoint decks (up to a 100 slides at times) using WCF. Aspose has been drawing each slide and generating all the shapes. It takes about 4-5 seconds for a deck to be generated. The loading of Aspose and small issues with Aspose can be irritating (one can process a slide in around 200ms). Also Aspose presentations are not serializable, which is annoying if you want to cache the results in some form.

If you want to read the PPTX and somehow convert it to images, Aspose.Slides is a good candidate because it allows you to convert a PPTX slide to SVG which you can subsequently process. Note that there are some PPTX2SVG engines out there (XSLT) but the ones I know are written in Java (Apache).

### Notes

The libraries I mentioned are all libraries for the .NET/C# environment. None of these libraries and techniques require office/interop/com installs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you deserve the reward but i've one question: It seems that i need to copy all the informations into a customized xml format ( don't ask why ) and i need to draw the custom xml format. Is it still the best choice to go with Aspose or is it better to go with OpenXML? I'm asking because OpenXML seems to fit my needs ( parsing ) because i need to extract the information and i don't need any further functionality on the pptx parser side ( Adding slides or whatever ).

Comment: You are right in your assessment that OpenXML is likely a better fit. Aspose provides you some tools to find the shapes or parts you need and then extract the data. However, it is not its primary purpose and its find functions are really not that strong (it is  geared to adding stuff). If you need pure extraction, OpenXML will be the best fit, particularly because you can use XPath to find the parts you are interested in which makes it easy. Documentation is a  bit fragmented, but is on MSDN. Also look at `ClosedXML` which is a parser for Excel that may help you understand OpenXML.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, it is not an easy task. I tried to do this for a Presentation Designer and it there are not many solutions in the wild.
I used Office Open XML SDk 2.5. which is significantly better than crunching the XML by hand, but no picknick either.
If you have some money, you coukd use: http://www.aspose.com/.net/powerpoint-component.aspx
I don't know how good it is.

I know this is not good news, but Powerpoint recieves significantly less attention than Excel, so the resources a scarce.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say if the application is going to have internet access, but assuming it is, you might think about using a public REST API to do the conversion of the PPTX into whatever format you need. There may be more, but here are a some that provide this functionality:

- [Aspose for Cloud Powerpoint API](http://www.aspose.com/cloud/powerpoint-api.aspx)
- [Doxument](http://www.doxument.com/)
- [ConvertAPI](http://www.convertapi.com/)

Some have free tier where you can do a certain amount of conversions per day without paying a usage fee. Aspose for Cloud has a .Net SDK, but with a REST API the language of the client shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, there is no clean and simple solution for this. In my opinion you are limited to 2 choices:

1. [Use Microsoft's own / VSTO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303718). Also info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668192.aspx). This is likely to give you a **lot** of headaches, but may be the only thing that gives you access to the PowerPoint features you require.
2. Use Open XML. This has already been covered. In likelihood this will be easier to use, but may not provide access to the features you require.

Beyond that I'm afraid you'll have to create something a lot more 'manual'.