# I need to show .pptx and .ppt file in android using third parties API

Tags: android, api, jar, powerpoint

i need to show .pptx and .ppt file in android using third parties API or jar, if anyone found related to that, please guide me to read and view the .ppt files in android. i tried last one day for that but i cant.Even i tried Apache poi and some GitHub projects but i can't get the clear output.

Comment: Show us what you tried and what problems you are facing

Comment: Even i cant able to find the correct solution about my search. That's what i tried @tiwari

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive comes with an excellent document viewer, and you can simply send docs to it by intent. It renders all Office docs (so far as I have seen) quite well.

```
import android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat;

Uri pptUri = Uri.parse("file://sdcard/sdcard0/test.ppt");                
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
                                     .setText("open ppt")
                                         .setType("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
                                         .setStream(pptUri )
                                         .getIntent()
                                 .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

And if you want to embed in your application a Third party lib : [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390715/creating-a-power-point-file-reader-pptx)

Comment: thanks for that rply sir , but i want to read .pptx from my own application like Documentmate and WPS office application  in playstore

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390715/creating-a-power-point-file-reader-pptx

Comment: Aspose.Slides ($$):----------------too cost
OpenXML (curve, but flexibility):-ts need to connect always with the                      internet while read the ppt files.
NetOffice (limited functionality):-Not for android only for .Net peoples

Comment: thanks for the rply sir, i searched those page what you guide me but those solutions are really not apt for me sir , i want to read the ppt files in offline like documentmate and wps they are did it very nice so i want to do like that